# unittest fails but no exception raised

Tags: python, unit-testing, network-programming

I have created a python script that connects to network devices, sends commands to them, and returns output. I'm trying to create a unittest that would check various configurations on the device itself. The unittest itself works fine, and I have a logger that does catch the errors, however stdout indicates that the test passes even though it isn't. I can't figure out what causes this issue.

```
def test_bios_version(self):
        command = "sh platform"
        output = SendCommandToConnectedDevice(device=self.device, command=command)
        expected_value = "16.12(2r)zzzzzzzz"
        try:
            self.assertIn(
                expected_value,
                output,
                f"Could not find {expected_value} when ran command {command}.",
            )
            self.logger.info(f"{expected_value} found in command {command}")
        except AssertionError as e:
            failure_message = f"Could not find {expected_value} when ran command {command}. Below is the output of the command:\n{output}"
            self.logger.error(failure_message)
```

This test is supposed to fail because the value is "16.12(2r)". The logger catches this error, but stdout prints this:

```
test_bios_version (__main__.TestingISRConfig) ... ok
```

logger prints:

```
2023-02-28 17:10:57,367 WARNING Could not find 16.12(2r)zzzz when ran command sh platform. Below is the output of the command: **deleted**
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you catching the assert exception inside your unit test? Why are you using logging in a unit test?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a raise Exception at the end of the unittest. The downside is that I have to add a manual raise for every test, but the output can also be custom, so that's pretty cool I guess. also, unittest will consider this as an ERROR as opposed to a FAIL test. This is not critical for my use-case, but it might be to yours.

```
except AssertionError:
        failure_message = f"command {command} was not successful."
        self.logger.error(failure_message)
        raise Exception(
            f"ping failed. Below is the output of the command:\n{output}")
```